# не получается импортировать less

Tags: gulp

таски

```
gulp.task('less', function(){ // Создаем таск "sass"
    return gulp.src('src/less/*.less') // Берем источник
        .pipe(less()) // Преобразуем less в CSS посредством gulp-less
        .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true })) // Создаем префиксы
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css')) // Выгружаем результата в папку src/css
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true})) // Обновляем CSS на странице при изменении
});
```

в лесс файле

```
@import "../less/libs/bootstrap.css";
```

на выходе в файл libs.css появляется то же самое

```
@import "../less/libs/bootstrap.css";
```

Comment: ошибок в консоли никаких не было при выполнении таски?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для нормального импорта css файлов в less достаточно указать ключевое слово (less), например вот так:

```
@import (less) url("../css/libs/slick.css");
```

И всё заработало ;)